# Help with SQL Server procedure rollback

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, exists

I need some help with this procedure:

What its supposed to do is try to insert a new user if there is no other with same NAME.

If there is a already an user, it should rollback else commit. But it doesn't work, it commits anyway.

Any suggestions?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_USUARIOS_INSERT]
@usu_ds varchar(50),
@usu_dt_create datetime,
@usu_dt_lst_log datetime,
@usu_ds_senha varchar(255),
@usu_ds_email varchar(100)
as
begin
declare @varCheckUser varchar(100) = null;
set @varCheckUser = (select COUNT(usu.usu_Ds) from Usuarios usu where usu.usu_ds = @usu_ds);
begin transaction
insert into Usuarios(usu_ds,usu_dt_create,usu_dt_lst_log,usu_ds_senha,usu_ds_email) values(@usu_ds,@usu_dt_create,@usu_dt_lst_log,@usu_ds_senha,@usu_ds_email)
if (@varCheckUser <> null)
begin
 RAISERROR('User already exists',16,1)
 rollback transaction
 return
end
else
begin
commit transaction
end
end
```

Comment: Did you evaluate the answer I gave? You can do the task in a single step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that @varCheckUser will ever be NULL, if there is no row it will be 0

```
set @varCheckUser = (select COUNT(usu.usu_Ds) 
from Usuarios usu where usu.usu_ds = @usu_ds);
```

this will make it 0

also you check like this for NULL

```
if (@varCheckUser IS NOT null)
```

why don't you do something like this

```
IF  EXISTS (select 1 
               from Usuarios usu 
                where usu.usu_ds = @usu_ds)
SET @varCheckUser =1
```

then check that it is not 1

why do you need the tran? Just do something like this

```
IF  EXISTS (select 1 
                   from Usuarios usu 
                    where usu.usu_ds = @usu_ds)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('User already exists',16,1)
RETURN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
insert into Usuarios(usu_ds,usu_dt_create,usu_dt_lst_log,usu_ds_senha,usu_ds_email)
values(@usu_ds,@usu_dt_create,@usu_dt_lst_log,@usu_ds_senha,@usu_ds_email)

END
```

Probably a good idea to make usu_ds  a `primary key` or add a `unique constrain`t, that way nobody can update their user name to something that exists and nobody can by mistake use SSMS and change a user name to something that is already in the table

Comment: what "IF EXISITS" checks?I didnt know this stamement

Comment: @ozsenegal: read up on EXISTS in the SQL Server Books Online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: @ozsenegal - `EXISTS` checks to see if a subquery returns a record.  If it does, then it evaluates true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your check to use `@varCheckUser = 0` - or better yet, change it to use `IF EXISTS` and only ever begin a transaction to insert the values if that user doesn't already exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Usuarios usu WHERE usu.usu_ds = @usu_ds)
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   INSERT INTO 
      dbo.Usuarios(usu_ds, usu_dt_create, usu_dt_lst_log, usu_ds_senha, usu_ds_email)     
   VALUES(@usu_ds, @usu_dt_create, @usu_dt_lst_log, @usu_ds_senha, @usu_ds_email)

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

There's really no point in starting a transaction just to roll it back, if you can check for the existance of the user before hand.

Plus: if the column `usu_ds` should be unique, you ought to put a UNIQUE constraint on it, too! That way, if you'll get errors (constraint violations) if someone manages to try and insert a user some other way (other than through your stored proc):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Usuarios
  ADD CONSTRAINT UX_usu_ds UNIQUE(usu_ds)
```

Comment: If you're going to write code like this, I think you should at least make a stab at handling concurrency properly. There's really no point in checking for the existence of the user beforehand if you don't take care of race conditions that make said existence check pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to that complicated.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_USUARIOS_INSERT]
   @usu_ds varchar(50),
   @usu_dt_create datetime,
   @usu_dt_lst_log datetime,
   @usu_ds_senha varchar(255),
   @usu_ds_email varchar(100)
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON 
INSERT Usuarios(usu_ds, usu_dt_create, usu_dt_lst_log, usu_ds_senha, usu_ds_email) 
SELECT @usu_ds, @usu_dt_create, @usu_dt_lst_log, @usu_ds_senha, @usu_ds_email
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Usuarios WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
      WHERE usu_ds = @usu_ds
   )
IF @@RowCount = 0 BEGIN
   RAISERROR('User already exists', 16, 1)
   RETURN
END
```

This code completely solves any concurrency problems for you as well (see [Conditional Insert/Update Race Condition](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

@varCheckUser can never be null.  It will always have a value that is a string representation of an integer.

Instead of:

```
if (@varCheckUser <> null)
```

Do:

```
if (@varCheckUser = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

@varCheckUser <> NULL will always return FALSE.

You must use @varChechUser IS NOT NULL